# How to create a 500m Regular Grid for KML input area?

Tags: qgis, kml, vector-grid

I am hoping to create a point grid over the city of Edmonton.  My workflow is:

1. Import a KML of Edmonton neighborhoods from [here](https://data.edmonton.ca/api/assets/8D4E54A9-9866-4449-86F0-4464E9B38BD4)
2. Save the layer as a SHP
3. Delete the layer and load the SHP
4. Define the layer and project CRS as NAD 83 (HARN)
5. Use the Vector > Research Tool > Regular Points tool to generate a grid of points over the geometry with a spacing of 500m.
6. Save the output and load into the project.
7. The output is a single point to the NW of the neighbourhood polygons.

I have been around this several time and am at a loss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're using a geographic coordinate system instead of a projected coordinate system.  Because NAD83 (HARN) uses degrees as the units, when you type in 500 in the grid spacing, it's using a spacing of 500 degrees, which is huge.  You'll need to reproject the data to a more suitable projected coordinate system which uses metres such as [UTM Zone 12N](http://georepository.com/projection_16012/UTM-zone-12N.html).  Once you use that coordinate system, you should be able to use the tool without any trouble.

This is the result I got:
[image]

Note, I live in Australia and I don't know which coordinate systems are most common for use in Canada.

Comment: This looks EXACTLY like what I want.  Thanks for the advise!  Other than changing the projection (which makes sense), did you modify the workflow that I posted?

Comment: Not really.  However, you can select the projection when you save out the shapefile.

Comment: I got it to work, but there seems to be some sort of conflict between the plug-ins.  As an experiment when I first loaded QGIS, I loaded all of the plugins available from the Plugins > Manage Plugins menu. From that time I could not get the Vector > Research Tools to work.  This time I unloaded all of the plugins, loaded only the fTools, and voila, the grid analysis worked.